# Selecting specific data SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to select the most recent and the first input of a specific variable from my database.

Im using the following:

```
SELECT treatment_log.fun FROM treatment_log LEFT JOIN customers ON treatment_log.treatment_fk=customers.id WHERE treatment_log.created_at=( SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM treatment_log) AND customers.id = ?

SELECT treatment_log.fun FROM treatment_log LEFT JOIN customers ON treatment_log.treatment_fk=customers.id WHERE treatment_log.created_at=( SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM treatment_log) AND customers.id = ?
```

One of the is MIN the other is MAX. Im trying to display the data based on the dates (created_at) [this is a timestamp auto generated]. The current code doesn't seem to work well. It will only display the data entered recently, and the display NULL.

**How do I upgrade this code?**

Comment: Please provide data and proper table structure and expected output so that question can be answered better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to qualify the subquery so that it only selects `created_at` dates for the customer you are interested in. Otherwise, you will get the MIN and MAX `created_at` dates regardless of customer id, and those may not match your current customer. This is why sometimes you get no data returned. Try changing the subquery to:

```
( SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ?)
```

So your whole query will become

```
SELECT treatment_log.fun 
FROM treatment_log 
LEFT JOIN customers 
    ON treatment_log.treatment_fk=customers.id 
WHERE treatment_log.created_at=(SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM treatment_log WHERE treatment_fk = ?) 
    AND customers.id = ?
```

You need to make a similar change to the `MIN` subquery as well.
Also note you will need to bind the `customers.id` value to this parameter as well.

Comment: Im trying to link the "fun" with the date. I'm not sure if this will do the job. Trying to display "fun" not the date.

Comment: @Joe What Nick is saying is that your subquery, `SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM treatment_log` (and the one for `MAX`), is completely disregarding the customer ID. It's going to grab the most recent and oldest date from the entire `treament_log` table, rather than grabbing the newest and oldest *by customer*.

Comment: @TylerRoper exactly! I'll edit my post with your comment (if you don't mind) to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: Perfect Thank you :)